# ata1, 2, 3 softreset failed

Tags: boot, 16.04

A couple of weeks ago, I installed ubuntu 16.04 for desktop (64-bit). It had been working flawlessly. After doing a couple of software updates, I get three errors on a restart/bootup:

- [2.484025] ata1: softreset failed (device not ready)
- [2.488023] ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
- [2.488106] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)

I have not been able to get past those errors. However, I am able to boot up in "recovery mode".

I searched the ubuntu forum for a similar problem but I have not been able to find a solution. Would anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48083/discussion-on-question-by-browndude16-ata1-2-3-softreset-failed).